# unsave change angularjs not working in ngDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Here discard & redirected using alert-- working](http://plnkr.co/edit/LF6Vnd68eVNhCKKFCsLn?p=preview)

[Here discard & redirect exdialog -  not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/ixawvayY9TapmQpWK3ht?p=preview)

```
Link 1 :
```

CheckStateChangeService allow to navigate if any changes on form asking confirmation alert using confirm message -- working fine

```
Link 2 :
```

CheckStateChangeService allow to navigate if any changes on form asking  ngexdialog box , its working but not redirect to another page